# Is there a way to refer to the CFBundleIdentifier elsewhere in the Info.plist file?

Tags: ios

For our game, in the Info.plist file, our `CFBundleIdentifier` is set as,

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.sixminute.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
```

But then, for Google Play Sign in, we need the following URL Types in `CFBundleURLTypes`,

```
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.sixminute.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.sixminute.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
        </array>
```

is there any way we could instead reference the `CFBundleIdentifier` dynamically like `$(BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` or similar?

Answer (score 5):

You can define user-variables in XCode in your target properties by following these steps :

1. Go to "Build settings" of your target app
2. Select Menu "Editor"-> "Add Build Setting" -> "Add User-Defined Setting"
3. Name your variable (e.g. "BundleId") and its value for each configurations

Then in your plist file you can simply use :

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>${BundleId}</string>
```

Comment: Not quite perfect, or what I was after, but still incredibly helpful.  If there's no other solution, without necessary additions, I'll mark this one as correct, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can not dynamically update CFBundleIdentifier later(or programmatically) and you can only add value to it compile time. Your question is also not clear, if you are referring something else.

BTW, CFBundleIdentifier and CFBundleURLName/CFBundleURLSchemes are completely orthogonal.